# Java if statements issue

Tags: java, if-statement

Old:

```
if (inv != troll) {
    System.out.println("Rock " + a);
}
if (hañ != troll) {
    System.out.println("Doll " + b);
}
if (tall != troll) {
    System.out.println("Mirror " + c);
}
if (troll != troll) {
    System.out.println("Note " + d);
}
End();
f++;
```

Updated:

```
if (!inv.equals(troll)) {
            System.out.println("Rock "+ a);}
            if (!hañ.equals(troll)) {
                System.out.println("Doll "+ b);}
            if (!tall.equals(troll)) {
                System.out.println("Mirror "+ c);}
            if (!high.equals(troll)) {
                System.out.println("Note "+ d);}
            End();
            f++;
```

I am doing a text adventure game and the items belonging in the if statements are arrays, the a b c d are random numbers generated which are sort of a password needed. Right here I am trying to display my inventory, so I want to know if there is any way for the conditions inside the if statement to be displayed as independents. In the sense that if the first is true it displays the first and if the second is not it only displays the ones that are true and then it goes to the method end. The problem I have is that right now all are false, but it still displays all of them except the last one.

I tried adding this in to my code which was given to me in the answers I am sorry I am editing the question its just that i don't know how to comment correctly. Concerning the answer now I am not sure if I am supposed to create a method for equals(); and if so what it should include. But using the updated code it still shows me the array lists even though inv for example has "Rock" inside the array and troll has no words in it.

Comment: How are the `inv` and `troll` variables declared? What is the type, `String`?

Comment: Put some else's in there. if() {  } else if() {  } else if () { }  ...

Comment: `if (troll != troll)` ... that doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes they are all declared in the class as, List<String> inv = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> hañ = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> tall = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> high = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> troll = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: What I am trying to do is so that if the arrays has somehting inside it displays the value, so I created troll as an extra empty array that has no given value. I don't think this is the best way I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please show the code in which you declare and fill the arrays. What do the arrays look like if there's nothing inside -- are they zero-length, or do they contain nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is so that if the arrays has somehting inside it displays the value, so I created troll as an extra empty array that has no given value.

To check if the `List` is empty use [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#isEmpty--):

```
if (!inv.isEmpty()) {

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly Thank you so much for your helo I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes they are all declared in the class as, List inv = new ArrayList(); List hañ = new ArrayList(); List tall = new ArrayList(); List high = new ArrayList(); List troll = new ArrayList();
>
> What I am trying to do is so that if the arrays has somehting inside it displays the value, so I created troll as an extra empty array that has no given value

If you initialize your variable this way and you just want to see if this is empty. you can do:

```
tall.isEmpty();
```

to check if it is empty.

But to be honest, this logic is not efficient. it will be better if you just create an object class of inventory with the following as attribute. It will be easier to handle everything.